# Galton Board Simulation

Tags: c, simulation, ascii-art, data-visualization, portability

This program is written for Windows 7 under MinGW using gcc.

I'm seeking recommendations for improving the program's portability.

```
/* galtonboard.c

   Galton Board Simulation (random mechanical cascade)

   notes: rate determines how often a ball is dropped
   e.g. 
       rate = 1  continuous; 1 ball on each row; up to 39 balls on the board
                 at once
            = 3  1 ball every 3 rows; up to 13 balls on the board at a time;
                 matches the vertical spacing of the pins
            = 39 1 ball every 39 rows; 1 ball on the board at a time
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

#define WIDTH           80
#define RTMARGIN        78
#define CENTER          39
#define NUMBEROFROWS    39
#define NUMBEROFBINS    13
#define PINGRAPHIC      "^"
#define BALLGRAPHIC     "*"
#define SPACEGRAPHIC    " "
#define BARGRAPHIC      "\xdb\xdb\xdb\xdb\xdb"

struct ballData
{
    int col;
    int dir;
};

void drawNumber (char scr[], const int row, const int col, int number)
{
    int position = row * WIDTH + col;

    do {
         scr[position] = number % 10 + '0';
        --position;
        number /= 10;
    }
    while ( number > 0 );
}

void drawString (char scr[], const int row, const int col,
     const char * const str)
{
    memcpy (&scr[row * WIDTH + col], str, strlen (str));
}

void checkBallInBin (char scr[], const int col, int * const count, int bin[])
{
    if ( col > 0 ) {
        ++*count;
        int binNumber = col / 6;
        ++bin[binNumber];
        drawNumber (scr, NUMBEROFROWS + 1, binNumber * 6 + 5,
                   bin[binNumber]);
    }
}

void checkNewBall (char scr[], const int col, int * const count,
     const int nBalls, struct ballData board[])
{
    if ( *count < nBalls ) {
        ++*count;
        drawNumber (scr, 2, col, *count);
        board[0].col = CENTER;
    }
}

void clearScreen (void)
{
    system ("cls");
}

void delay (const int interval)
{
    Sleep (interval);
}

void displayScreen (const char scr[])
{
    puts (scr);
}

int numberLen (int number)
{
    int digitCount = 0;

    do {
        ++digitCount;
        number /= 10;
    }
    while ( number > 0 );

    return digitCount;
}

void drawPercent (char scr[], const int row, int col, int number)
{
    drawString (scr, row, col, "%");
    --col;

    int tenthsDigit = number % 10;
    number /= 10;

    if ( number != 100 ) {
        drawNumber (scr, row, col, tenthsDigit);
        --col;
        drawString (scr, row, col, ".");
        --col;
    }    

    drawNumber (scr, row, col, number);
}

void drawHistogram (char scr[], const int bin[])
{
    for ( int i = 2; i <= NUMBEROFROWS - 2; ++i )
        memset (scr + i * WIDTH + 1, ' ', RTMARGIN - 1);

    drawString (scr, 2, 1, "frequency histogram");

    int sum = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFBINS; ++i )
        sum += bin[i];    
    drawString (scr, 2, RTMARGIN - 1 - numberLen (sum) - 8, "\xe4 bins =");
    drawNumber (scr, 2, RTMARGIN - 1, sum);

    // histogram height at 100 percent = 34 rows
    // constant of proportionality -- fraction of rows representing 1 %
    const float k = 34 / 100.0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFBINS; ++i ) {
        float frequency = 100.0 * bin[i] / sum;
        int barHeight = (int) (k * frequency);
        for ( int j = 0; j < barHeight; ++j )
            drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS - 1 - j, i * 6 + 1, BARGRAPHIC);
        drawPercent (scr, NUMBEROFROWS - 1 - barHeight, i * 6 + 5,
                    frequency * 10);
    }
}

void drawInitialScreen (char scr[], const int nBalls)
{
    drawString (scr, 0, 1, "Galton Board Simulation");

    for ( int i = 1; i < CENTER - 1; ++i ) {
        drawString (scr, 1, i, "\xc4");
        drawString (scr, 1, i + CENTER + 1, "\xc4");
    }
    drawString (scr, 1, 0, "\xda");
    drawString (scr, 1, RTMARGIN, "\xbf");
    drawString (scr, 1, CENTER - 1, "\xd9");
    drawString (scr, 1, CENTER + 1, "\xc0");

    for ( int i = 2; i <= NUMBEROFROWS - 2; ++i ) {
        drawString (scr, i, 0, "\xb3");
        drawString (scr, i, RTMARGIN, "\xb3");
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFBINS; ++i ) {
        drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS - 1, i * 6, "\xb3");
        drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS, i * 6 + 1,
                   "\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc5");
        drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS + 1, i * 6, "\xb3");
        drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS + 2, i * 6 + 1,
                   "\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc4\xc1");
    }
    drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS - 1, RTMARGIN, "\xb3");
    drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS, 0, "\xc3");
    drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS, RTMARGIN, "\xb4");
    drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS + 1, RTMARGIN, "\xb3");
    drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS + 2, 0, "\xc0");
    drawString (scr, NUMBEROFROWS + 2, RTMARGIN, "\xd9");

    drawString (scr, 2, 1, "random mechanical cascade");
    drawString (scr, 2, RTMARGIN - 1 - numberLen (nBalls) - 2, "of");
    drawNumber (scr, 2, RTMARGIN - 1, nBalls);

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFBINS - 1; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j <= i; ++j )
            drawString (scr, (i + 1) * 3,  CENTER - i * 3 + j * 6,
                       PINGRAPHIC);
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFBINS; ++i )
        drawNumber (scr, NUMBEROFROWS + 1, i * 6 + 5, 0);
}

void drawOrEraseBalls (char scr[], const struct ballData board[],
     const char * const str)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFROWS; ++i ) {
        if ( board[i].col > 0 )
            drawString (scr, i, board[i].col, str);
    }                
}

int randomNumber (const int range)
{
    // return an integer between 0 and range - 1
    return rand() % range;
}

void moveBallsDown (struct ballData board[])
{
    for ( int i = NUMBEROFROWS - 2; i >= 0; --i ) {
        if ( board[i].col > 0 ) {
            if ( i % 3 == 2 ) {
                // pin
                if ( randomNumber (2) == 0 )
                    board[i].dir = -1;
                else
                    board[i].dir = 1;
            }
            board[i].col += board[i].dir;
        }
        board[i + 1] = board[i];
    }

    board[0] = (struct ballData) { 0, 0 };
}

void setCursorTopLeft (void)
{
    const COORD coord = { 0, 0 };

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}    

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // these are the default values -- use a cmd line argument to change them
    // first cmd line argument = number of balls to drop
    // second cmd line argument = rate (how often a ball is dropped)
    int numberOfBalls = 1024, rate = 1;

    if ( argc > 1 )
        numberOfBalls = atoi (argv[1]);
    if ( argc > 2 )
        rate = atoi (argv[2]);

    if ( rate <= 0 ) {
        printf ("\nProgram halted: the variable 'rate' must be > 0\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // screen length = 41 80-char lines + 1 79-char line
    const int scrLen = 3359;
    char scr[scrLen + 1];
    memset (scr, ' ', scrLen);
    scr[scrLen] = '\0';
    struct ballData board[NUMBEROFROWS] = { { 0, 0 } };
    int bin[NUMBEROFBINS] = { 0 };
    const int milliseconds = 20;
    srand (time(NULL));

    clearScreen ();
    drawInitialScreen (scr, numberOfBalls);
    const int dropCountCol = RTMARGIN - 1 - numberLen (numberOfBalls) - 4;

    int catchCount = 0, cycle = 0, dropCount = 0;

    do {
        checkBallInBin (scr, board[NUMBEROFROWS - 1].col, &catchCount,
                       bin);
        moveBallsDown (board);
        if ( cycle == 0 )
            checkNewBall (scr, dropCountCol, &dropCount, numberOfBalls,
                         board);
        drawOrEraseBalls (scr, board, BALLGRAPHIC);
        displayScreen (scr);
        delay (milliseconds);
        setCursorTopLeft ();
        drawOrEraseBalls (scr, board, SPACEGRAPHIC);

        ++cycle;
        cycle %= rate;
    }
    while ( catchCount < numberOfBalls );

    drawHistogram (scr, bin);
    displayScreen (scr);

    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The inclusion of the header file windows.h will cause this to not compile in any non-Windows environment.

---

From the MAN page for `memcpy()`:

> The  memcpy()  function  copies  n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap.  Use memmove(3)  if  the memory areas do overlap.

---

The statement `system( "cls" );`  will cause an error in most environments, other than Windows. I suggest using the ANSI escape sequences.

---

The statement `Sleep (interval);` will fail to compile in most environments. Using `sleep()` (lowercase S) may work, but is discouraged, I suggest using `nanosleep()`.

---

Regarding `const float k = 34 / 100.0;`, the `100.0` is a `double` literal. I suggest: `const float k = 34 / 100.0f;`.

---

Regarding `SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);`, neither `SetConsoleCursorPosition()` nor `GetStdHandle()` nor `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` are available outside the Windows environment.

---

Regarding `srand (time(NULL));`: this will not work in an environment that does not have a RTC (Real Time Clock).

---

Regarding `const int scrLen = 3359;`: this is making an assumption about the terminal layout that (mostly) is not true. I suggest setting a newline '\n' at the 79th column of each row of the `scr` array.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I considered using memmove (instead of memcpy), however, there didn't seem to be any possibility of overlap. The suggestion about double and float in the histogram calculation was something I had not considered. Putting a '/n' at the end of each line of output would prevent using the fast puts command which outputs the entire screen at once. I have essentially no experience with Linux -- would using the ncurses library allow the program to run on Windows and Linux boxes?

Comment: no overlap???  The source and destination completely overlap each other. (offset by 1 byte)

Comment: suggest not using `ncurses` until you have a lot more experience.

Comment: Note: embedding newlines in the `scr[]` array will have no problems for the `puts()` functionality.